# How can I deal with data binding flickers in AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have directive with a few nested directive inside of it. One of the directive using ng-reppeat to bind data inside ul/li list, while others directive are just a templates for basic data bind.

The problem I see while loading the page - The simple data-bind directives are loaded first so you see them at first on page, while the ng-repeat directive is being seen on page after a few mili-seconds later, so the all componenet is being flickering.

How can I deal with it? How can I tell the father directive to show all its sub-directive data-binded on the same time? I do use {{data-bind}} inside my directives.

Please advice how to avoid this kind of things on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use ng-cloak. Add specific styles in your `<head>` (so they get loaded before AngularJS).

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need [ngCloak, see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)